# How to invoke enum value specific method outside of enum?

Tags: java, enums

I have enum like this:

```
  public enum Email{
        WELCOME,
        LOGIN       
    }
```

`EmailService` has following method signature:

```
public void sendEmail(String from, String subject, String[] to, Map<String, String> props, String templateFileName)
```

I want to have API like this:

```
Email.WELCOME.send(from, subject, to, welcomeProp1, welcomeProp2....)



Email.LOGIN.send(from, subject, to, loginProp1, loginProp2....)
```

To acheve this I tried to add specific methods to enum fields:

```
public enum Email{
    WELCOME{
        public void send(String param1,String param2,String param3,String param4){
           ....    
        }
    },
    LOGIN{
        public void send(String anotherParam1,String anotherParam2,String anotherParam3){
            .... 
        }
    }
}
```

But I found out that I could not invoke this methods outside of enum. To acheve it I need to create abstract method and override in each enum value. But problem that signature of these methods are different and it is impossible to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: the send method must be declared in the Email, not in its instances.

Comment: @mrmcwolf - They have different signatures.

Comment: Just curious, does it have to be an enum? This seems like it should be done with an interface and objects instead

Comment: if the method have different siganture, create different methods. Don't create the method in the property, create it in the Enum Email and call it sendWelcome, sendLogin, etc.

Comment: So you're confusing the architecture. Enum declares static institutions of one class. If you want different behavior from the instances, you must give them the additional strategy (strategy pattern)

Comment: @ Nick DeFazio, maybe, please provide you design phoughts. But I want to have mesage types as enum anyway

Comment: Enums are the wrong tool for this. At least in the way given in pseudocode. Also looks like a very procedural attempt at writing the code, so you might want to consider another design, instead of hacking around with enums.

Comment: @Kayaman feel free to propose new design

Comment: The issue here is that you have a template file which causes you to lose the strong typing you're hoping to have in your `Email.FOO.send(someparams)` style code. In the end you can't really do much better than passing a map of properties.

Comment: @Kayaman yep, But i want to have all email lists in single place and if person adds template - he should not forget  all parameters

Comment: But it's not enforceable, typesafe or automatable. Therefore a weak solution.

Comment: @Kayaman agree, but I could not find better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use polymorphism for in such case. First of all, define some interface, for instance:

```
public interface Message {
}
```

Then you should add an abstract method to the enum:

```
public abstract void send(Message message);
```

After that, create two child classes - the first one is for WELCOME and the second one is for LOGIN:

```
class WelcomeMessage implements Message {
    private String param1;
    private String param2;
    private String param3;
    private String param4;

    // constructor, getters
}

class LoginMessage implements Message {
    private String anotherParam1; 
    private String anotherParam2; 
    private String anotherParam3;

    // constructor, getters
}
```

Then add implementations of `send()` method:

```
public enum Email {
    WELCOME {
        public void send(Message message) {
            WelcomeMessage wm = (WelcomeMessage) message;
            ....    
        }
    },
    LOGIN {
        public void send(Message message) {
            LoginMessage lm = (LoginMessage) message;
            .... 
        }
    }
}
```

UPD.
@gstackoverflow mentioned that it's possible to invoke methods with "incorrect" implementation. I guess I know how to prevent this.

```
public enum Email {
    WELCOME {
        protected void sendInternal(Message message) {
            WelcomeMessage wm = (WelcomeMessage) message;
            ....    
        }

        protected Class<? extends Message> getSupportedClass() {
            return WelcomeMessage.class;
        }
    },
    LOGIN {
        protected void sendInternal(Message message) {
            LoginMessage lm = (LoginMessage) message;
            .... 
        }

        protected Class<? extends Message> getSupportedClass() {
            return LoginMessage;
        }
    };

    public static void send(Message message) {
        for (Email email : values()) {
            if (email.getSupportedClass().equals(message.getClass()) {
                email.sendInternal(message);
            }
        }
    }
    protected abstract void sendInternal(Message message);
    protected abstract Class<? extends Message> getSupportedClass();
}
```

Comment: good point but how to forbid to invoke **LOGIN.send(new WelcomeMessage())** ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow I have thoughts about it. Will update my answer

Comment: It would be better to have this check on compilation phase but I could not imagine better, thus I will implement my task at this manner

Comment: I agree, but think it's impossible with enums)

Comment: Well this is certainly an overly complicated way to send mail.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to make all the methods take exactly the same object, they just use different parameters from it.

```
class EmailDetails {
    String param1;
    String param2;
    String param3;
    String param4;
    String anotherParam1; 
    String anotherParam2; 
    String anotherParam3;
}

public enum Email {
    WELCOME {
        public void send(EmailDetails details) {
            System.out.println("Welcome!!");
        }
    },
    LOGIN {
        public void send(EmailDetails details) {
            System.out.println("Log in!!");
        }
    };

    public abstract void send(EmailDetails details);
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    Email.WELCOME.send(new EmailDetails());
    Email.LOGIN.send(new EmailDetails());
}
```

You will generally find that many of the fields are common to all uses.

Comment: What if we have lots of enums, 5 or even 10? EmailDetails will be too big, with not ordinary amount of fields

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon, I think that it would be ok to create hierarchy of EmailDetails. I want to force client of this method to pass all parameters which this email need to render message

Comment: @MykolaYashchenko - That would be a sign that the overall design is questionable. Enums should be used to group similar entities. If they all need different parameters then you probably should not be using enums.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon god class is also antipattern :)